# Flash IDE and AS3 Blank Space

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I was working on a 'as' file and then ctrl+entered the project. Only thing I see is empty scene. The earlier test was fully functional and visual. Is there anything about 'fla' size or so?

---

There is a mouse event at the very beginning and it does not go to the event function.

---

```
public function Game()
{
// constructor code
    init(0);
}
private function init(level:int):void
{
    switch (level)
    {
        case 0 :
            pis = new Yesil;
            yldz_bir.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoFirst, false, 0, true);
            yldz_bir.buttonMode = true;
            break;
        case 1 :
                pis = new Yesil;
                item_speed = 3;
                _puan = 0;
                initialMain();
                point.texts.text = "0";
                can = 4;
                main();
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you be a little bit more specific concerning your question?

Comment: @ gPeart It looks it is empty 'fla' and no 'as' file. There is a mouse event which nearly initiate everything and since it does not fire event function nothing appears on screen.

Comment: could you share the correspondent code?

Comment: Corresponding code part added.

Comment: I got what was wrong. Sorry, my bad.